# Is there multi arange in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

Numpy's arange accepts only single scalar values for start/stop/step. Is there a multi version of this function? Which can accept array inputs for start/stop/step? E.g. having input 2D array like:

```
[[1 5 1], # start/stop/step first
 [3 8 2]] # start/stop/step second
```

should create array consisting of concatenation of aranges for every row of input (each start/stop/step), input above should create 1D array

```
1 2 3 4 3 5 7
```

i.e. we need to design such function that it does next:

```
print(np.multi_arange(np.array([[1,5,1],[3,8,2]])))
# prints:
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 7])
```

And this function should be efficient (pure numpy), i.e. very fast process input array of shape `(10000, 3)` without pure-Python looping.

Of cause it is possible to create pure Python's loop (or listcomp) to create arange for each row and concatenate results of this loop. But I have very many rows with triples start/stop/step and need to have efficient and fast code, hence looking for pure numpy function.

Why do I need it. I needed this for several tasks. One of this is for indexing - suppose I have 1D array `a` and I need to extract many (possibly intersecting) subranges of this array. If I had that multi version of arange I would just do:

```
values = a[np.multi_arange(starts_stops_steps)]
```

Maybe it is possible to create multi arange function using some combinations of numpy functions? Can you suggest?

Also maybe there are some more efficient solutions for the specific case of extracting subranges of 1D array (see last line of code above) without creating all indexes using multi_arange?

Comment: Trying to understand the dataset - What's the min and max on the step values?

Comment: @Divakar start, stop, step can be arbitrary numbers, no minimum or maximum, same that are accepted by `np.arange()`, for now may be just integers (and floats in possible future later).

Comment: @Divakar You may optimize your solution for the case when there are always thousands of triples start/stop/step, not just few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one with `cumsum` that accounts for positive and negative stepsizes  -

```
def multi_arange(a):
    steps = a[:,2]
    lens = ((a[:,1]-a[:,0]) + steps-np.sign(steps))//steps
    b = np.repeat(steps, lens)
    ends = (lens-1)*steps + a[:,0]
    b[0] = a[0,0]
    b[lens[:-1].cumsum()] = a[1:,0] - ends[:-1]
    return b.cumsum()
```

If you need to validate for valid ranges : `(start < stop when step > 0)` and `(start > stop when step < 0)` , use a pre-processing step :

```
a = a[((a[:,1] > a[:,0]) & (a[:,2]>0) | (a[:,1] < a[:,0]) & (a[:,2]<0))]
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  1],
       [ 3,  8,  2],
       [18,  6, -2]])

In [18]: multi_arange(a)
Out[18]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  3,  5,  7, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10,  8])
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice solution! And pure numpy. I've tested your solution, it is 7 times faster on my PC, but some output values are wrong (see my answer to own question) (different from naive and my solutions). I've implemented `numba` solution which is 25 times faster than naive, but If we find numpy only solution then would be best.

Comment: @Arty Some of your data has stop = start. Those are causing that issue. You need to remove those.

Comment: BTW, how difficult to change your solution to cover all cases? I.e. cases stop <= start and negative step also? Do you support currently negative step?

Comment: Also do you know the reason why numba is 25 times faster while numpy solution is only 7 times? Is there some pythonic code in some lines of your code which can slow down or some inefficient computation?

Comment: @Arty Negative step would be tough I think. For covering cases `stop <= start`, feed in   `a[a[:,1] > a[:,0]]` as the input or do that as pre-porcessing inside.

Comment: `numpy 0.79559 sec |||
arty_multi_arange 0.03202 sec 24.84 speedup ||| 
divakar_multi_arange 0.10457 sec 7.61 speedup`

Comment: @Arty Yeah, on negative step, swap 1st, 2ncdol. Then set 3rd col as positive.

Comment: Do you know if there is also some faster (than using multi_arange func) way of extracting thousands of sub-ranges from huge 1D array? Of cause that can be done using `values = a[multi_arange(starts_stops_steps)]` but maybe there is a faster solution without creating intermediate array of indexes?

Comment: @Arty Sorry, I don't know any other NumPy vectorized method. Added solution to handle `negative stepsizes` and `stop <= start` cases.

Comment: Do you mean that running `multi_arange(a)` now is enough for negative steps and empty ranges? Or I need to do preprocessing by myself? BTW, you compute `lens` twice in your code, looks like typo.

Comment: @Arty Yup. Yeah just consider the second line of `lens`. Preprocessing is needed when you have `[89, 213, -5]` or `[8, 0, 5]`. I suppose you would have come back with that case in the future. Makes sense?

Comment: @Arty So, that pre-procecssing is needed to remove the cases when you would have empty ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: np.r_[1:5:1, 3:8:2]
Out[1]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 7])

In [2]: np.hstack((np.arange(1,5,1),np.arange(3,8,2)))
Out[2]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 7])
```

The `r_` version is nice and compact, but not faster:

```
In [3]: timeit np.r_[1:5:1, 3:8:2]
23.9 µs ± 34.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [4]: timeit np.hstack((np.arange(1,5,1),np.arange(3,8,2)))
11.2 µs ± 19.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a way to provide very large array of starts/stops/steps, e.g. input is array of shape [1000, 3], i.e. 1000 triples of start/stop/step. And I need to have multi arange for all these 1000 triples without any pure python looping, just fast numpy functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just came up with my solution using `numba`. Still I prefer `numpy`-only solution if we find best one not to carry heavy numba JIT compiler.

I've also tested @Divakar solution in my code.

Next code output is:

```
naive_multi_arange 0.76601 sec
arty_multi_arange 0.01801 sec 42.52 speedup
divakar_multi_arange 0.05504 sec 13.92 speedup
```

Meaning my `numba` solution has 42x speedup, @Divakar's `numpy` solution has 14x speedup.

Next code can be also [run online here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64004559#main.py).

```
import time, random
import numpy as np, numba

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def arty_multi_arange(a):
    starts, stops, steps = a[:, 0], a[:, 1], a[:, 2]
    pos = 0
    cnt = np.sum((stops - starts + steps - np.sign(steps)) // steps, dtype = np.int64)
    res = np.zeros((cnt,), dtype = np.int64)
    for i in range(starts.size):
        v, stop, step = starts[i], stops[i], steps[i]
        if step > 0:
            while v < stop:
                res[pos] = v
                pos += 1
                v += step
        elif step < 0:
            while v > stop:
                res[pos] = v
                pos += 1
                v += step
    assert pos == cnt
    return res
    
def divakar_multi_arange(a):
    steps = a[:,2]
    lens = ((a[:,1]-a[:,0]) + steps-np.sign(steps))//steps
    b = np.repeat(steps, lens)
    ends = (lens-1)*steps + a[:,0]
    b[0] = a[0,0]
    b[lens[:-1].cumsum()] = a[1:,0] - ends[:-1]
    return b.cumsum()
    
random.seed(0)
neg_prob = 0.5
N = 100000
minv, maxv, maxstep = -100, 300, 15
steps = [random.randrange(1, maxstep + 1) * ((1, -1)[random.random() < neg_prob]) for i in range(N)]
starts = [random.randrange(minv + 1, maxv) for i in range(N)]
stops = [random.randrange(*(((starts[i] + 1, maxv + 1), (minv, starts[i]))[steps[i] < 0])) for i in range(N)]
joined = np.array([starts, stops, steps], dtype = np.int64).T

tb = time.time()
aref = np.concatenate([np.arange(joined[i, 0], joined[i, 1], joined[i, 2], dtype = np.int64) for i in range(N)])
npt = time.time() - tb
print('naive_multi_arange', round(npt, 5), 'sec')

for func in ['arty_multi_arange', 'divakar_multi_arange']:
    globals()[func](joined)
    tb = time.time()
    a = globals()[func](joined)
    myt = time.time() - tb
    print(func, round(myt, 5), 'sec', round(npt / myt, 2), 'speedup')
    assert a.size == aref.size, (a.size, aref.size)
    assert np.all(a == aref), np.vstack((np.flatnonzero(a != aref)[:5], a[a != aref][:5], aref[a != aref][:5])).T
```